# How to find whether an appointment exists by ApointmentId

Tags: exchangewebservices

I used Appointment.Bind() & pass in ApointmentId. If it exists it return all the details about the appointment, if not it doesn't throw any exception but gives some appointment object.

I want to how to figure out if appointment exists or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ID represents an item that's not there, you should get a `ServiceResponseException` with the message `The specified object was not found in the store.` The SOAP response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="207" MinorBuildNumber="19" Version="V2_47" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
          <m:MessageText>The specified object was not found in the store.</m:MessageText>
          <m:ResponseCode>ErrorItemNotFound</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
          <m:Items />
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Jason, many thanks, so this works, only if i cancel a meeting & then i try to bind it, it throw ServiceResponseException. I was testing giving some invalid, but well formed id to bind method, however that used to give some or other object in return.